# WooCommerce taxonomy: category and children

Tags: woocommerce, taxonomy

I am using a logic filter for my widgets. I want to restrict my widget to display only if current category is child of category 49. I use:

`is_product_category() && in_array($cat, get_term_children( 49, 'product_cat'))`

As I understand it, 49 is the id of the parent and product_cat is the desired taxonomy.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No answer anywhere. I ended up using a plugin to solve my problem: https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-widgets/